# Correct syntax for Canonical - link or meta tag?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, meta-tags

I'm getting a little confused about adding canonical tags to pages. Some ([most](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)?) guides suggest using a link tag thusly:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.example.com/somepage" />
```

but some [others](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=17c9730c48214183&hl=en) suggest a meta tag like so:

```
<meta rel="canonical" href="www.example.com/somepage" />
```

Are both allowed? Which is right? If one is wrong, where does the confusion stem from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The first one is correct](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html). There is a [meta tag for acknowledging the original work if you republish content](http://googlenewsblog.blogspot.com/2010/11/credit-where-credit-is-due.html) but that is something else entirely.